# Посмотреть старую версию уже не рабочего сайта

Tags: site

Есть сайт который по определенным причинам мне очень нужно посетить, но дело в том что он уже не работает и при заходе появляется ошибка.

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Возможно ли как-то все же посмотреть его хотя-бы прежнее содержимое? Пытался через Web Archive зайти на snapshot ещё якобы рабочей версии, но там появляется всё та же ошибка `403`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Web Archive. Если последние версии содержат ошибку, то посмотреть более ранние.
2. Google, Яндекс и другие поисковики. Рядом с результатом поиска обычно показывается ссылка на кэшированную версию.

[image: google]

[image: яндекс]